# operator does not exist timestamptz < interval(in seconds)

Tags: time, error-handling, compiler-errors, vertica

I want to perform very simple SELECT in Vertica, but have an error that can't understand. This is my code:

```
SELECT 1
FROM tbl_one,tbl_two two
WHERE id = two.id
AND TYPE = 'some_type'
AND amount > 0 LIMIT 1
AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP -
(SELECT MIN(two.some_data)
FROM tbl_one,tbl_two two
WHERE id = two.id) < INTERVAL '5 days';
```

And error:

```
ERROR 4286: Operator does not exist: timestamptz < interval(in seconds)
HINT: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You may need to add explicit type casts
```

Tell me please what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try putting brackets around the last `AND ` statement.  Like  `(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP -
(SELECT MIN(two.some_data)
FROM tbl_one,tbl_two two
WHERE id = two.id))`

Comment: doesn't work - the same error

Comment: Move `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` inside the sub-query. Also, what is the type of `some_data`

Comment: Just to be clear, are you saying that what GoBrewers14 was suggesting didn't work? `SELECT 1
      FROM tbl_one one
      JOIN tbl_two two USING (id)
     WHERE TYPE = 'some_type'
       AND amount > 0
       AND (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - (
           SELECT MIN(two.some_data)
             FROM tbl_one,tbl_two two
            WHERE id = two.id
           )) < INTERVAL '5 days'
     LIMIT 1
    ;`

Comment: Yes, because some_data's type is varchar, thanks to Kermit comment. Now I don't know how to change varchar to timestamp...

Answer (score 0):

I resolved a similar issue with the [TIMESTAMPADD function](https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.2.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/Date-Time/TIMESTAMPADD.htm).

Using this the last line of the condition becomes:

```
AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP < TIMESTAMPADD(DAY, 5, (
  SELECT MIN(two.some_data)
  FROM tbl_one,tbl_two two
  WHERE id = two.id
))
```